# How to get embedded Spring-Cloud-Server to read github properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to embed a spring cloud server with git hub. Following this link right [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/280).

Also following the following [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html)

**pom.xml**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>
...
```

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
@RefreshScope
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Value("${prop1:default}") private String prop1;
    @Value("${prop2:default}") private String prop2;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/world", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHelloWorld() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("Message: ")
                .append(prop1).append(" ")
                .append(prop2).append("!")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=root-server
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= www.githubrepo/config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username = username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password = password
```

Spring cloud GIT Repository file

**${user.home}/Desktop/config/root-server.properties**

```
prop1=Hello
prop2=World
```

**Output**

localhost:8080/hello/world

```
Message: default default!

It should be Message: Hello World!
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the properties in the above application.properties to bootstrap.properties like the documentation you linked. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/280

Comment: @yongsung.yoon Yes, I have tried that. Still did not work. updated post.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?